# How to enforce exclusion constraint?

Tags: sql-server-2008, composite-primary-key

I have the following table with two columns:

```
A - int (null)
B - int (null)
```

There should be a value in A or B but not both.  How do I create this constraint?

Without an extra IDENTITY column, is there a way to enforce a composite primary key on this table due to two null columns being allowed?

Comment: What do you mean by "composite primary key"? Is there a requirement for uniqueness?

Comment: It's a composite primary key.  So yes - it should be unique.

Comment: What should be unique? The combination of `(A,B)` or `A UNION ALL B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table t 
(  
   a int,
   b int, 
   CONSTRAINT null_const CHECK ((a is not null and b is null) or 
                                (b is not null and a is null))
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you show the composite primary key as well?

Comment: This syntax is creating errors in the constraint: column 'b' references another column, table 't'.

Comment: Was missing final comma.  Thanks.